# Writing temp files on domino server using java: what is the best practice for the temp directory?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I am writing a Java Agent which does some attachment manipulations and I am looking for a 'clean' place where I can do the manipulations - i.e. won't have too much hassles with admins setting special permissions. Is there a best practise for the location of the temp directory? In Lotusscript I would use

```
Environ("Temp")
```

which would give me the temp directory of the local machine.

There is also the possibility of using the data directory, but that makes me uneasy...

```
var d = session.getEnvironmentString("directory",true)
```

Any tips/best recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule is if you need a temp directory, then request it from the system.

Example:

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

Using the Data folder is probably going to upset the admin.

If you want to create diagnostic logs which you may use later then I recommend writing to:

```
<DOMINO DATA FOLDER>\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT
```

This way the admin has one set place to find logs.

Answer (score 1):

An example could be

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");
temp.deleteOnExit(); //This will delete the file when the JVM shuts down.
```

That file would be saved in

```
C:\Users\*User*\AppData\Local\Temp\temp-file-name623426.tmp
```